# How to pass a string between two activities

Tags: android

I am just starting with Android development and I have a problem. I am trying to the next thing:

I have an Activity1 that has a button, "0". Also I have Activity2 that has a TextView and an OK button.

When I press on "0", I want to pass some string to Activity2.

When I press on 0, Activity2 has to open, and in it TextView have to show the string that I passed. After pressing on OK (in Activity2), I want to come back to the Activity1.

I tried to do this in this way:

**Activity1**

```
case R.id.b0:
    errorString = "Error: a number can't start with 0";
    Bundle basket = new Bundle();
    basket.putString("error", errorString);
    Intent person = new Intent("my.firsttraining.app.vitali.ERRORPAGE");
    person.putExtras(basket);
    startActivity(person);
```

**Activity2**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    bOK= (Button)findViewById(R.id.bOKonError);
    errorDisplay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvError);

    bOK.setOnClickListener(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.errorpage);

    Bundle gotBasket = getIntent().getExtras();
    String error = gotBasket.getString("error");
    errorDisplay.setText(error); ``
```

I also tried to do something like this:

**Activity1**

```
case R.id.b0:
    errorString = "Error: a number can't start with 0";
    basket = new Bundle();
    basket.putString("error", errorString);
    person = new Intent("my.firsttraining.app.vitali.ERRORPAGE");
    person.putExtras(basket);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, person);
    finish();
```

**Activity2**

```
    bOK.setOnClickListener(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.errorpage);
}

public void onClick(View v)
{
    Intent in = new Intent("my.firsttraining.app.vitali.MENU");
    startActivity(in);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        Bundle gotBasket= data.getExtras();
        String err = gotBasket.getString("error");
        errorDisplay.setText(err);
    }
}
```

After all this, I have an error. After clicking on Button 0, my application crashes. I get the following error.

> The application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again

and the button with text "Force Close".

I have to say that I do not really understand the second option. I just saw it in some tutorial.

Comment: Please post the logcat output for the crash.

Answer (score 1):

In your Activity2.java write `setContentView(R.layout.errorpage);` after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` so that view can be intit and then you can get button form view.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Just write this line. You it will load view for 
        //activity and then you can get button from it
        setContentView(R.layout.errorpage);

        bOK= (Button)findViewById(R.id.bOKonError);
        errorDisplay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvError);

        bOK.setOnClickListener(this);        

        Bundle gotBasket = getIntent().getExtras();
        String error = gotBasket.getString("error");
        errorDisplay.setText(error);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, so now i understand what is the right order in code and that is very important.